# user_id in signed request but no oauth_token

Tags: facebook

I've had an app in a Facebook tab and suddenly it begins to crash.
The problem is that I used to get the signed_request and pass the oauth_token, so if I had problems getting the user I set the access token using that value.
Suddenly, the signed request doesn't pass the oauth_token value but the user_id is correct, but in the documentation its said: "Some fields and values, the user_id and oauth_token for example will only be passed if the user has logged into your app".

This is a bug or Facebook is changing the API?

I'm using the code value passes in the signed request to set the token, is that correct? If not, how can I use this "code" value?

Thanks